# Sorting images with Stupid-table-plugin

Tags: javascript, sorting, jquery-plugins, html-table

I'm ordering a table with jquery **plugin Stupid-table**.
The text and the numbers are sorted correctly but now I want to order three images: **01.jpg, 02.jpg and 03.jpg**. The code for my table is as follows:

```
<table id="ranking">
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th data-sort="string">Name</th>
      <th data-sort="medall">Medal</th>
      <th data-sort="string">Año</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>Belmonte, Frank</td>
       <td><img src="01_medal_gold.png" alt="Gold"></td>
       <td>2012</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Smith, Adam</td>
       <td><img src="02_medal_silver.png" alt="Silver"></td>
       <td>2009</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Riva, Emma</td>
       <td><img src="03_medal_bronze.png" alt="Bronze"></td>
       <td>2013</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Could you tell me how I can order these three images with the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `data-sort-value="..."` to the table cells with the images and then add a custom sort algorithm for this type.

```
<tr>
   <td>Riva, Emma</td>
   <td data-sort-value="3"><img src="03_medal_bronze.png" alt="Bronze"></td>
   <td>2013</td>
</tr>
```

.

```
$("table").stupidtable({
    medall: function(a, b) {
        // sort algorithm...
        return parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10);
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdaZD/)

Comment: Actually, if you go through the trouble of adding a data-sort-value with an integer value, all you have to do is sort by int.